# Postgresql convert Japanese Full-Width to Half-Width

Tags: cjk

I am manipulating Japanese data and in some Japanese words, there are English words and Numbers are in.

ＳＹＳＫＥＮ, 松井ケ丘３, コメリＨ＆Ｇ, 篠路７－１ are the examples.

I wanted to convert these English and Numbers in Full-width to half-width by throwing a function or any possible ways.

the output of the input above should be look-like "SYSKEN, 松井ケ丘3, コメリH&G, 篠路7-1"

If anyone knows the best way to start, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using translate() function?

```
-- prepare test data
CREATE TABLE address (
    id integer,
    name text
);
INSERT INTO address VALUES (1, 'ＳＹＳＫＥＮ, 松井ケ丘３, コメリＨ＆Ｇ, 篠路７－１');

-- show test data
SELECT * from address;

-- convert Full-Width to Half-Width Japanese
UPDATE address SET name = translate(name,
    '０１２３４５６７８９ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ',
    '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
);

-- see the converted data
SELECT * from address;
```

This code made the name column to "SYSKEN, 松井ケ丘3, コメリH＆G, 篠路7－1".

Comment: this is the code i used to test  ```select distinct(name_ja), translate(name_ja, '０１２３４５６７８９ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ', '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') as trans
  from japan_data 
  where name_ja in ('ＲＣ－６', '北鹿持ＮＯ．３児童公園', 'ベルフラワー', '４０１', 'イ－７', 'ＢＯＯＫ・ＯＦＦ', 'ＥＮＥＯＳ', 'シェル', 'Ｇ２ビル')```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres 13 (but not 12) has a `normalize()` text function

[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html#:~:text=normalize%20(%20text%20%5B%2C%20form%20%5D%20)%20%E2%86%92%20text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html#:%7E:text=normalize%20(%20text%20%5B%2C%20form%20%5D%20)%20%E2%86%92%20text)

> `normalize ( text [, form ] ) → text`
>
> Converts the string to the specified Unicode normalization form. The optional `form` key word specifies the form: `NFC` (the default), `NFD`, `NFKC`, or `NFKD`. This function can only be used when the server encoding is UTF8.
>
> ```
> normalize(U&'\0061\0308bc', NFC) → U&'\00E4bc'
> ```

Your example results in

```
SELECT normalize('ＳＹＳＫＥＮ, 松井ケ丘３, コメリＨ＆Ｇ, 篠路７－１', NFKD);

               normalize               
---------------------------------------
 SYSKEN, 松井ケ丘3, コメリH&G, 篠路7-1
```

Note that characters such as the `,`, fullwidth space, `-`, and `&` were also transformed.

The NFKD normalization algorithm also affects many other characters, in addition to full-width and half-width characters.
That may or may not be appropriate depending on why you are normalizing.

For example, you can remove the "fraktur" style "font" using `NFKD`.

```
SELECT normalize('', NFKD);
 normalize 
-----------
 fraktur
(1 row)
```

Check the Unicode specification for details on how the normalization algorithm works:

https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms